# Authenticate SignalR from MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am learning ASP.NET Identity and SignalR among other stuff. I was able to create my own authentication system using a custom implementation of Identity. I am now trying to authenticate the user to SignalR before calling the overridden OnConnected.
After the user gets authenticated using the Cookie Authentication, the `[System.Web.Mvc.Authorize]` attribute passes succesfully, while the `[Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR]` attribute tells me that the user has not authenticated yet.

```
//This is my Authorize method:
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Authorize()
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new ClaimsIdentity(new ClaimsPrincipal(User).Claims.ToArray(), "Bearer"));
    return new EmptyResult();
}

//This is my CookieAuthenticationOptions
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
});

//On the Hub
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    string userName = Context.User.Identity.Name; //User is null?
}
```

What I am missing here? I have googled for some time and I'm not able to find anything, not even an idea on how to authenticate to SignalR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably you're mapping SignalR before the authentication, You must map SignalR after authentication:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Index")
        });

        //...

        app.MapSignalR();    
}
```

Comment: That was it! In Startup.cs, under Configuration(IAppBuilder), app.MapSignalR() was before ConfigureAuth. Thank you! It now works